# Can't get fb user's information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting started with Fb app development. I tried to deploy the example app given in the facebook php api but don't seem to get it working

Here is the code:-

```
<?php


require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '**************',
  'secret' => '**************************',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {

  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {


  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/aitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

But $user is always null, and it shows "You are not connected".
Is it because I'm using a free webhost and not having any secured URL?

Url of my app, if you want to see: http://apps.facebook.com/iiiimags

Comment: My guess would be: _“third party cookies” problem_, once again …

Comment: By _searching_ for that keyword I gave you …